# converting string to to Map in Java

Tags: java, json, hashmap, jackson

I am converting a object into string  using jackson Objectmapper and saving it into database as a varchar2.My code is

```
AuditDataLog dataLog = new AuditDataLog();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
dataLog.setData(mapper.writeValueAsString(obj));
```

it is saved into database as a Varchar2.but when i retrieve this value from data base and want to convert it into Map using ObjectMapper it can't do that.it gives exception like this

```
"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [map type; class java.util.HashMap"
```

Here is my code

```
Map map = mapper.readValue(obj,HashMap.class));
```

obj is database value which is string.this is string  from which i want to convert map.

```
"\"MerOrder\":{\"cusAccPartyId\":\"4632\",\"cusAccParty\":{\"fullName\":\"Kariban\"},\"merAccPartyId\":\"4800\",\"merAccParty\":{\"fullName\":\"Golam Sarwer\"},\"season\":\"a455\",\"tfReceiveDate\":\"26 Apr 2017\",\"styleName\":\"a123\",\"styleNo\":\"s345\",\"sizeRange\":\"1\",\"merVariantValue\":{\"name\":\"XL-XS\"}}"
```

What should I do??

Comment: What you are saving is no hashmap. It is an object of type `MerOrder`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it fails becuase the `String` you are trying to deserialise is not a valid `json`, you need to wrap it into curly braces in order to make it a valid `json`. Below should work fine:

```
String s = "\"MerOrder\":{\"cusAccPartyId\":\"4632\",\"cusAccParty\":{\"fullName\":\"Kariban\"},\"merAccPartyId\":\"4800\",\"merAccParty\":{\"fullName\":\"Golam Sarwer\"},\"season\":\"a455\",\"tfReceiveDate\":\"26 Apr 2017\",\"styleName\":\"a123\",\"styleNo\":\"s345\",\"sizeRange\":\"1\",\"merVariantValue\":{\"name\":\"XL-XS\"}}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
HashMap value = mapper.readValue("{" + s + "}", HashMap.class);
System.out.println(value);
```